# AppleScript without Admin privileges, how can I get a users preferred time to open App?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an automation script that I'm working on for my coworkers to try and make their station setup easy each time. The computers are reset each day and we dont have admin access so it takes us 15 mins to set up each time.

I've managed to cut this down to a minute with a script that opens and positions 90% of the apps and website tabs needed. Its pretty limited though because I cant use things like System Events to move non-supported apps

The problem with automating the desktop setup is that people come in 20-40 minutes before their shift, and there is an App we can only open one minute before the shift starts. If I'm automating everything, they can spend time chatting and getting other things done, BUT it may result in users forgetting to open the app, or opening it too early and getting into trouble.

I know how to set a specific time that an app can open, but I need it to work on a variation of shifts, which can be one of 20 different shift starts, so to make it more convenient I would need a text field or drop down menu

I dont know of a way I can use AppleScript to do this though.

Are there any other creative ways I can pull this off?

Comment: You know, I've seen a few of your posts now, and I suggest that you go to your manager and pitch to have him hire someone to write a proper log-in script. Call it a matter of efficiency... You can find a ton of people on this site who would do it, get proper administrative access to make it work right, and earn yourself some kudos (and maybe a bonus) for the suggestion.  Just sayin... 

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a current versions of Mac OS, you can use AppleScript Objective-c to make more complex dialogs than the standard ones. For instance, if you want to make a popup menu for times, you can do something like this:

```
use framework "Foundation"

property ca : current application
property NSPopUpButton : class "NSPopUpButton"
property NSAlert : class "NSAlert"
property NSArray : class "NSArray"

set timeList to {"8:00", "9:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "..."}
set popUpFrame to ca's NSMakeRect(0, 0, 215, 26)
set timePopup to NSPopUpButton's alloc()'s initWithFrame:popUpFrame pullsDown:false
timePopup's addItemsWithTitles:(NSArray's arrayWithArray:timeList)

set alert to NSAlert's alloc's init
alert's addButtonWithTitle:"Select"
alert's addButtonWithTitle:"Cancel"
alert's |window|()'s setTitle:"Start Time"

alert's setAccessoryView:timePopup

set modalResponse to 0 as integer
set modalResponse to alert's runModal() as integer
if modalResponse is equal to ca's NSAlertFirstButtonReturn then
    set returnedValue to timePopup's titleOfSelectedItem() as text
end if
```

The will allow the user to choose a time, and put the string they choose in `returnedValue`.

If you'd prefer a time-picker kind of thing, that can be done as well, but maybe this is enough to get you started.

Edit: to run scripts that display windows or alerts, you need to put them in the foreground. That means that (from the Script Editor) you have to use ^⌘r or choose 'Run' from the 'Script' while holding down the control key. Otherwise you'll get an annoying alert message, or Script Editor will crash (fairly gracefully). That only makes a difference when you're running from the Script Editor; from the Script Menu or an app it'll work fine.